# Can I still monetize a Youtube video if I redirect website traffic to it?

Tags: google-adsense, youtube, google-adsense-policies

Will Google ban me if redirect my website traffic to my Youtube video? Ban in the sense, will I be able to monetize my Youtube video still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't ask the users to click the ads and the users are not bots or traffic from services like paid-to-click, paid-to-surf, autosurf and click-exchange programs, you should be good.

Check and go through the Google AdSense support article [Top invalid traffic and policy violations that lead to account closure](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2660562?hl=en) for more information on what you can and cannot do with regards to funneling traffic.